WinSock2 accept function causes access violation when used in multiple threads of one process
I am working on designing libraries in C and C++ for my company's proprietary language through ffi. The two libraries which are causing the problem related to the title are the threads and sockets libraries.
threads.cc
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

DWORD WINAPI thread_call(void* data)
{
    void** datap = (void**)data;
    
    void*(*datafn)(void*) = (void*(*)(void*))datap[0];
    datafn(datap[1]);

    return 0;
}

extern "C" {
void* gc_alloc(int size);

char* create_thread(char *(*worker)(char *), char *data) {
    void** datap = (void**)gc_alloc(sizeof(char*(*)(char*))+sizeof(char*));
    datap[0] = (void*)worker;
    datap[1] = (void*)data;

    HANDLE* handle = (HANDLE*)gc_alloc(sizeof(HANDLE));
    *handle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, thread_call, datap, 0, NULL);
    return (char*)handle;
}

void close_thread(char* th) {
    HANDLE* thandle = (HANDLE*)th;
    CloseHandle(*thandle);
}
}

sockets.cc
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "../websocket.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#define BUFFER_SIZE 2048

extern "C"
{
    // called at the entry of the program in the proprietary language
    int windowsStart()
    {
        WSADATA wsaData;
        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    // called at the end of the program in the proprietary language
    void windowsCleanup()
    {
        WSACleanup();
    }

    void *gc_alloc(int bytes);
    char* runtime_int_to_string(int number);

    SOCKET create_socket(int port)
    {
        int iResult;

        SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

        struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
        struct addrinfo hints;

        int iSendResult;

        ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
        

        // Resolve the server address and port
        iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, runtime_int_to_string(port), &hints, &result);
        if (iResult != 0)
        {
            printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Create a SOCKET for the server to listen for client connections.
        ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
        if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Setup the TCP listening socket
        iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        freeaddrinfo(result);

        iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        return ListenSocket;
    }

    int open_socket(int *port, bool *run_socket, char *(*request_handler)(char *, char *), char *data)
    {
        SOCKET ListenSocket = create_socket(*port);
        SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

        int iSendResult;
        int iRecvResult;

        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while (*run_socket)
        {
            ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL); // this is where the error occurs

            if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
                printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ListenSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }

            iRecvResult = recv(ClientSocket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);

            char *response = request_handler(data, buffer);
            iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, response, strlen(response), 0);
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }

            close_socket(ClientSocket);
        }
    }
}

Then, two threads with their own sockets are created in a similar fashion to what follows:
char* requestHandler(char* data, char* request) {
    ...
}

char* worker(char* data) {
    bool runSocket = true;
    open_socket((int*)data, &runSocket, requestHandler, NULL);
}

int main() {
    int port1 = 1234;
    int port2 = 4321;

    windowsStart();
    create_thread(worker, (char*)(&port1));
    create_thread(worker, (char*)(&port2));
    windowsCleanup();
}

If this code were to execute properly, two sockets (one on port 1234 and the other on port 4321) would be continuously running and awaiting a request until the program is ended by the user.
Instead what happens is the first thread runs with success and creates the first socket, but when the second thread is created, the program exits when the accept function is called from the open_socket function.
When inspecting the error raised by calling the accept function a second time through Application Verifier, it states "First chance access violation for current stack trace"
Why is it that the first thread runs with no issues but the same exact code fails in the second thread?
Note: Some of the function definitions or code within the functions may look oddly placed or bizarre, and this is due to the fact that this code has to link with my companies proprietary language through c ffi.
Edit: call to open_socket in the example had incorrect arguments

Here is the issue: Why do you call WSACleanup() on every failure?

In the call open_socket(*((int*)data)), which open_socket function are you calling? It can't be int open_socket(int *port, bool *run_socket, int *socketfd, char *(*request_handler)(char *, char *), char *data) because there's an argument mismatch. Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us.

And generally, there's just too many pointers and too many explicit C-style conversions (casts) going on. Use type-aliases. Use structures. Use void* if you really need old-style generic pointers (which you don't actually need, there are better ways to do it in C++). Use static_cast for conversions.

@Someprogrammerdude I would like to have less pointers, but the code uses many pointers because the libraries that interact with this c++ from the proprietary language my company uses utilizes a lot of pointers.

@Someprogrammerdude You also did catch my mistake not providing the correct arguments to the open_socket function, so I fixed that. Thank you.

If you've been forced into stuff like void*(*datafn)(void*) = (void*(*)(void*))datap[0]; you have my utmost pity, but I do recommend not passing this on to whoever follows you on this project. The real value of a programmer is often seen in how rarely their name is used as a vicious epithet after they leave the company. std::thread and a capturing lambda should sort this right out if you can use a compiler that supports C++11 or higher.

@user4581301 Thank you for this tip, its been a while since I've worked with c++ so I forgot about std::thread. I'll give it a try and if it works I'll post it as an answer. Thank you for the pity, I will take it and pass it down to the next poor soul to work on this project.

I see a number of issues with your code.
create_socket() returns a SOCKET not an int, so it should return INVALID_SOCKET (-1) on error instead of 1. And open_socket() needs to check for that condition. In fact, open_socket() needs to do better error handling in general.
You are also missing return statements in functions that have non-void return types, which is undefined behavior.
Your main() is not waiting for the worker threads to finish running before shutting down Winsock. And absolutely do not call WSAShutdown() on every socket failure, you will unload Winsock prematurely by doing that. WSAStartup() and WSACleanup() need to be balanced.
Your ClientSocket loop should not return on a recv() or send() failure. Just close the ClientSocket and go back to accept().
Don't force char* everywhere. You should be using void* instead. Most of your type-casts can be eliminated.
Try something more like this:
threads.cc
#include <windows.h>

typedef void* (*thread_fn)(void*);

struct thread_data {
    thread_fn func;
    void *user;
};

DWORD WINAPI thread_call(void *data)
{
    thread_data *datap = (thread_data*) data;
    datap->func(datap->user);
    return 0;
}

extern "C" {

void* gc_alloc(int size);

void* create_thread(thread_fn worker, void *data) {
    thread_data *datap = (thread_data*) gc_alloc(sizeof(thread_data));
    datap->func = worker;
    datap->user = data;

    HANDLE* handle = (HANDLE*) gc_alloc(sizeof(HANDLE));
    *handle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, thread_call, datap, 0, NULL);
    if (*handle == NULL) return NULL;
    return handle;
}

void close_thread(void *th) {
    HANDLE* thandle = (HANDLE*) th;
    CloseHandle(*thandle);
}

void wait_thread(void *th) {
    HANDLE* thandle = (HANDLE*) th;
    WaitForSingleObject(*thandle, INFINITE);
}

}

sockets.cc
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include "../websocket.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#define BUFFER_SIZE 2048

static bool wsaInit = false;

extern "C"
{
    // called at the entry of the program in the proprietary language
    int windowsStart()
    {
        WSADATA wsaData;
        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0)
            return 1;

        wsaInit = true;
        return 0;
    }

    // called at the end of the program in the proprietary language
    void windowsCleanup()
    {
        if (wsaInit)
            WSACleanup();
    }

    void* gc_alloc(int bytes);

    SOCKET create_socket(int port)
    {
        int iResult;

        SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

        struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
        struct addrinfo hints;

        int iSendResult;

        ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;        

        // Resolve the server address and port
        char portStr[12];
        sprintf(portStr, "%d", port);
        iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, portStr, &hints, &result);
        if (iResult != 0)
        {
            printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
            return INVALID_SOCKET;
        }

        // Create a SOCKET for the server to listen for client connections.
        ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
        if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            return INVALID_SOCKET;
        }

        // Setup the TCP listening socket
        iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            freeaddrinfo(result);
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            return INVALID_SOCKET;
        }

        freeaddrinfo(result);

        iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            return INVALID_SOCKET;
        }

        return ListenSocket;
    }

    int open_socket(int *port, bool *run_socket, char* (*request_handler)(void*, void*, int), void *data)
    {
        SOCKET ListenSocket = create_socket(*port);
        if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
            return 1;

        SOCKET ClientSocket;

        int iResult;
        int iSendResult;
        int iRecvResult;

        char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while (*run_socket)
        {
            fd_set readfd;
            FD_ZERO(&readfd);
            FD_SET(ListenSocket, &readfd);

            timeval tv;
            tv.tv_sec = 1;
            tv.tv_usec = 0;

            iResult = select(0, &readfd, NULL, NULL, &tv);
            if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("select failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ListenSocket);
                return 1;
            }

            if (iResult == 0)
                continue;

            ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);

            if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
                printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ListenSocket);
                return 1;
            }

            iRecvResult = recv(ClientSocket, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
            if (iRecvResult <= 0) {
                if (iRecvResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                continue;
            }

            char *response = request_handler(data, buffer, iRecvResult);
            iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, response, strlen(response), 0);
            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                continue;
            }

            close_socket(ClientSocket);
        }

        close_socket(ListenSocket);
        return 0;
    }
}

#include <iostream>

char* requestHandler(void *data, char *request, int request_size) {
    ...
    return ...;
}

struct worker_data {
    bool *runSocket;
    void *user;
};

void* worker(void *data) {
    worker_data *datap = (worker_data*) data;
    open_socket(datap->user, datap->runSocket, requestHandler, NULL);
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    int port1 = 1234;
    int port2 = 4321;
    bool runSocket = true;

    windowsStart();

    worker_data wd1;
    wd1.runSocket = &runSocket;
    wd1.user = &port1;
    void *th1 = create_thread(worker, &wd1);

    worker_data wd2;
    wd2.runSocket = &runSocket;
    wd2.user = &port2;
    void *th2 = create_thread(worker, &wd2);

    std::cout << "Press a key to exit\n";
    std::cin.get();

    runSocket = false;

    if (th1) {
        wait_thread(th1);
        close_thread(th1);
    }

    if (th2) {
        wait_thread(th2);
        close_thread(th2);
    }

    windowsCleanup();
}

